# Как остановить выполнение js если не получен post параметр?

Tags: javascript

В дефолтном js для всех страниц сайта имеется функция обновления чата

```
function updatePosts() {
    $.post(dle_root + "engine/modules/chat/scripts/ajaxLoad.php", {
        ub_id: ub_id
    }, function(s) {
        var e;
        JSON.parse(s).forEach(function(s) {
        Number(s.id) > Number(last_message_id) && (session_user == s.username ? $("#messages-wrapping").append(load_self_message(s.message, s.username)) : $("#messages-wrapping").append(load_message(s.message, s.username))), e = s.id
    }), last_message_id = e
})
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$.post(dle_root + "engine/modules/chat/scripts/ajaxLoad.php", {
    ub_id: ub_id
}, function(s) {
    JSON.parse(s).forEach(function(s) {
        session_user == s.username ? $("#messages-wrapping").append(load_self_message(s.message, s.username)) : $("#messages-wrapping").append(load_message(s.message, s.username)), last_message_id = s.id
    })
})
}), setInterval(updatePosts, 2000);
```

На страницах, где работа чата не предусмотрена, получаю постоянную ошибку в консоли каждые 2 секунды:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: ub_id is not defined**

Как в js выполнить проверку на **ub_id** и не выполнять скрипт, если ub_id не определен?

Comment: `ub_id is not defined`, а при чём тут post параметр?

Comment: ub_id в ajaxLoad.php передается post запросом, возможно что-то путаю. Ваш ответ помог решить мою проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как в js выполнить проверку на ub_id и не выполнять скрипт, если ub_id не определен?

```
if (typeof ub_id !== 'undefined') {/* ... */}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.